# Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Looking to solve this error that I'm getting when trying to display some data to the view. I'm working with v5.7 and I have a feeling it might be something with the index method in my controller, I could be very wrong. If there is any more info that is needed please let me know.

> Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object (0)

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/category/{category}','BlogController@category')->name('category');
```

**BlogCategory Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BlogCategory extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug']; 

   public function posts()
   { 
     return $this->hasMany(Post::class); 
   }

   public function getRouteKeyName()
   { 
     return 'slug'; 
   }
}
```

**Post Model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
protected $limit = 3;

public function index()
{
    $categories = BlogCategory::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->published();
    }])->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();

    $posts = Post::with('author')
        ->latestFirst()
        ->published()
        // ->filter(request()->only(['term','year','month']))
        ->simplePaginate($this->limit);

    return view('pages.frontend.blog.index', compact('posts', 'categories'));
}

public function category(BlogCategory $category)
{
    $categoryName = $category->title;

    $categories = BlogCategory::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->published();
    }])->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();

    $posts = $category->posts()
        ->with('author')
        ->latestFirst()
        ->published()
        ->simplePaginate($this->limit);

    return view("pages.frontend.blog.index", compact('posts', 'categories', 'categoryName'));
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <article class="post-item">
        @if ($post->image_url)
            <div class="post-item-image">
                <a href="{{ route('blog.show', $post->slug) }}">
                    <img src="{{ $post->image_url }}" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="post-item-body">
            <div class="padding-10">
                <h2>
                    <a href="{{ route('blog.show', $post->slug) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                </h2>
                {!! $post->excerpt_html !!}
            </div>

            <div class="post-meta padding-10 clearfix">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <ul class="post-meta-group">
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            <a href="#"> {{ $post->author->name }} </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            <time> {{ $post->date }}</time>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                            <a href="{{ route('category', $post->category->slug) }}"> {{ $post->category->title }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                            <a href="#">4 Comments</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="{{ route('blog.show', $post->slug) }}">Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
@endforeach
```

**Post table**
[image: post table]

**Blog Cats table**
[image: Blog category]

Comment: Should $post->category->slug in the view be  $posts->category->slug

Comment: The view is in a foreach ill post the rest of the code.

Comment: Seems that your post hasn't fetched the related category. Not knowing Laravel particularly well, do you need to define another `with()` for the category? Or you could just pass `$category` to the view since it should be the same for all the posts getting fetched?

Comment: In your Post::category relationship function, add the `->withDefault();`, this will make your relationship fallback to a new Model instead of null in case there's no relation between post and category.

Comment: when I do that I get a different error: `Missing required parameters for [Route: category] [URI: category/{category}].`

Comment: Quick answer: `->withDefault(['slug' => '']);`. Why is this happening? You have a relationship flaw, Laravel could not find the relationship (you either set it up wrongly, or one post in particular has null category_id, which is making the whole thing fall under the foreach). A good practice is to checking the relationship with an if else before using it... `@if ($post->category)` `@endif` in bladd

Comment: Do all your posts definitely have a category? Do you at least know which line of code if causing the error??

Comment: There are 5 Categories, when I do a `dd($categories)` I see all 5. I seeded the DB with 35 post and all are assigned a category ID. If Im on the home/Blog page the index throws the error. when I got to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/news` page the category method throws it.

Comment: Can you provide the schema of your posts and categories table?

Comment: added some images of the DB tables is there anything else you would need besides that?

Comment: Just wrote an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `belongsTo` function accepts a second argument for the name of the foreign key in your posts table, if you do not provide it the framework will try to guess what is the foreign key column name giving the name of the function as pattern, in your case `category()`, so the framework is searching for `category_id`, however, your foreign key column name is `blog_category_id`.

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class, 'blog_category_id');
}
```

Comment: I guess If I would have finished reading the docs this wouldn't have happened. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should call the category relationship in the index of your controller, if this view is related to the index method!

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = BlogCategory::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->published();
    }])->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();

    $posts = Post::with('author')
        ->category()
        ->latestFirst()
        ->published()
        // ->filter(request()->only(['term','year','month']))
        ->simplePaginate($this->limit);

    return view('pages.frontend.blog.index', compact('posts', 'categories'));
}
```